# Can I bring 500 grams of gold while travelling to Canada for 2 weeks on a visit visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, airport-security, import-taxes

Can I bring 500 grams of gold while travelling to Canada for 2 weeks on a visit visa?

It’s my first time visiting Canada and I’m a bit worried.
Some answers might help. I will bring it back with me and can’t leave it alone where I live

Comment: That's >$30000 USD of gold. It'll look suspicious and will raise a lot of questions, I imagine

Comment: To the commenters suggesting the OP convert the gold into something else -- presumably, if they wanted the gold to be not-gold, they could have done so already. They came into the gold somehow, they can turn it back into money and put that money in a bank. They could also find a safe place to leave the gold while they're on vacation, like a safe deposit box, or a mattress, or a hole in the ground. This question is asking specifically how to carry $30k in gold through a foreign country like an emotional support hamster and get away with it, not asking whether it's a good idea, which it is not.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152285/discussion-on-question-by-izza-can-i-bring-500-grams-of-gold-while-travelling-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Note that even if they let it in, you're going to be flagged for inspection on the way out, so unless you plan on taking all of it back home with you you're going to have to deal with import/export/tax...

Comment: Can you say whether your 500g is in the form of ingots, or jewellery?

Answer (score 29):

I am not a lawyer, and the language of [Non-Taxable Imported Goods (GST/HST) Regulations](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-91-31/fulltext.html?wbdisable=true) is a bit thick, but it looks like gold (a precious metal) could be tax exempt, if it's imported temporarily, following the [Temporary Importation Regulations](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/dm-md/d8/d8-1-1-eng.html). You might want to contact the Canadian authorities – or a lawyer, or a Customs broker – to help you prepare for this. Showing up with 500 grams of gold and a smile will not be a good strategy...

As mentioned in the comments, a bank safe will be cheaper and much less hassle...

Comment: Banks don't have "bank safes" any more.  It is really, really tricky to find somewhere to store gold (in most, but not all, jurisdictions).

Comment: @Fattie: citation needed. AFAIK most banks still have them.

Comment: @Fattie "safe deposit box" and "safety deposit box" may a term you are more familiar with, but they are still widespread in their use

Comment: In many areas of the US, you must be on a waiting list for years to get a safe deposit box at a bank. They aren't very profitable, so they don't make more of them.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi If I remember correctly, Fattie lives in Norway and there, most banks have indeed stopped offering safety deposit boxes. In Germany, where I live, many banks are only offering online services and do not have branch offices at all anymore. Even traditional banks are closing many of their branch offices. Without a physical bank office, there will also be noe safety deposit boxes to rent.

Comment: In Asia and the middle east there are still lots of banks offering this service. Owning physical gold is still very common.

Comment: @Doryx - this question is USA.  There are about 80,000 bank branches in the USA and maybe 20 branches have safe deposit boxes. (And those are in like "downtown Manhattan.") They are unheard of in the US.  (BTW as an icnredible coincidence, I own a couple of historic deposit boxes (European), some were sold off as objet d'art when they stopped being a thing in banks in the 70?s.)

Comment: @Fattie - yet somehow I have accounts at two banks (well, credit unions) in different states, each of which has multiple branches with available safe deposit boxes. And my parents, in yet another state, also have a bank with multiple branches all with safe deposit boxes. I find it hard to believe that 3 institutions that I can access have all the safe deposit boxes in the US...

Comment: @Fattie maybe it got deleted but where did OP say where they are flying from? Also I am not sure what you are talking about but you are flat out wrong. Many national chains offer them as well as local banks. Large metros will have many, small towns will have them as well (small town of 15k had at least 2 banks that offered safety deposit boxes)

Comment: There are also non-bank companies that offer safe deposit box services. These are often armored car companies, but also facilities that serve the jewelry trade. Keywords: vaulting facility, private vaults, bullion depository.

Comment: @Fattie Not that terribly important but I cannot see anything in the question that would make it US-specific.

Comment: The OP asked 2 questions about visiting Canada for 2 weeks on a tourist visa. Probably not flying from the US...

Comment: @Fattie Chiming in on the safety deposit box question, my bank has eight locations in my city that offer them.  If this city is typical, there should be hundreds of such branches in the US just from this one (very large) bank, not 20 overall.

Comment: While we are veering completely off-topic, in the UK safe deposit boxes in banks are quite difficult to find as well. Some will have a service to hold an envelope for you (e.g property titles), but if you want to store objects the choices are much more limited, often involving dedicated companies, or, funnily, Selfridges (long waiting list last time we inquired) or Harrods. In France OTOH the device is still relatively common in bank branches, though probably on the way out.

Comment: @Gábor you're completely correct, my bad.  I think the OP mentioned US in a deleted comment, or I may have misread another comment.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the purposes you are bringing the goods for and depending on your country of origin, you may be able to use an [ATA Carnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Carnet) to import your goods duty-free, as long as you plan to re-export them.

You would be required to pay a deposit equivalent to the amount of duties owed in the case that the goods are not re-exported by the required date. There may also be processing fees involved with obtaining the ATA Carnet itself.

Generally, ATA Carnets are valid for 1 year from the date of issuance and cover "virtually all goods" [[2](https://chamber.ca/programs-services/ata-carnet/)]. To obtain an ATA Carnet, the best place to look is with the chamber of commerce or customs office in your country of origin.

I am not a lawyer. I am not *your* lawyer. This is not legal advice.

Comment: I'm afraid OP's country of origin is the issue why they can't leave the gold home. Should that be the case, I doubt going to the customs office and telling a government officer "hey, I got half a kilo of gold here, can I get a passport for it?" will end on a good note.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica Even if they don't get a Carnet, if the OP is flying from their home country (which is most likely), it is going to be very hard for them to hide the gold when they depart. So it's win/win for their government/customs.

Comment: @PeterM I believe OP intentionally left some important minutia of his situation out of the question to protect themselves. A naive approach might be harmful.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica I can't think of any real scenario of the OP getting to Canada without flying.  Because if they were coming overland from the US they would have other options.

Comment: @mlmlmlmmlmlmlmlml We have no idea what the OP is doing with his gold, how they obtained or the legality of the situation.  But there is nothing inherently illegal with owning gold bars.  So unless you have proof otherwise it is reasonable to answer what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike some other countries the official consumer-friendly guidance for import of currency-like items does not mention gold (at least the one I found did not), however I would definitely declare it to Canada Customs.

My understanding is that gold bars or ingots of over a certain percentage (something like 99.5% purity) are not taxed with GST/HST/PST and are not subject to duty. This is distinct from jewelry items which are subject to taxation. Hence it should be treated similarly to a wad of cash. Not taxed, but you likely need to declare it if it exceeds $10,000, and there should be little risk to that unless it is a result of the proceeds of crime or being used to finance terrorism.

Note that importation of Russian gold is [currently prohibited](https://www.osler.com/en/resources/regulations/2022/canada-bans-russian-gold-imports-and-export-of-various-manufacturing-services-and-designates-disin) with some exceptions.

I **don't** consider this answer to be sufficient considering the amounts involved are relatively large and I urge you to **call** Canada Border Service and ask. They are both competent and helpful and will give you better (and more up-to-date) advice than you might find here. They do answer the phone, unlike some countries.

BTW, gold is easily detected (as I found when I was carrying some different alloys around with me).

Answer (score -2):

This may sound crazy, but perhaps you can ship it to your destination with insurance, and then ship it back.  This would cost some money but if something went wrong you could be made whole.  Apparently depending on the method you can buy insurance for up to $50,000.  I don't know about any specific regulations or duties that might apply.

https://shippingeasy.com/resources/shipping-insurance-coverage-limits-included/

Comment: I do not think the OP is worried about physically carrying the gold with him, but what will happen at the border because of customs: is it forbidden? will there be duties? could the officers become suspicious of the OP being involved in an illegal activity? Sending the gold through shipping would not solve of any those issues; if at all, it could make the OP more suspicious by trying to avoid border controls.

Comment: I would think nothing would happen at the border. If anything were to happen with the package it would most likely be at the shipping end. And if anything happened later, the insurance would pay out. When the traveler crosses the border the gold wouldn't even be mentioned. As far as I know, "have you shipped anything recently?" isn't one of the questions they ask.